# How to align the bar charts in a stacked bar chart properly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats, overleaf

I'm working on this latex code to fit the bounds properly. I want to include the percentage on top of every bar plot, and the legend must be simply a rectangle. Also, can anyone please help me use patterns in this code?

Code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[][Sub figure first]{\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=12pt,
        ylabel={$\mathcal{J}$ of WM},
        nodes near coords,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90},
        xtick = data,
        table/header=false,
        table/row sep=\\,
        xticklabels from table={\footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize 
          % wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          % \footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\
          }{[index]0},
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper}
      %  legend pos=north west
    ]
     \legend{1\%, 5\%}
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{1\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\};
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{3\\2\\8\\4\\4\\2\\};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,3,4,7,8,11}{\coordinate(l#1)at(axis cs:#1,0);}
    \end{axis}
    \coordinate(bbs)at(current bounding box.south);
    \foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\s=int(4*\i-1)},evaluate={\e=int(4*(\i-1))}] \text in {Axial,Coronial}
      \draw[decorate,decoration=brace]([xshift=8pt]l\s|-bbs)--node[below=5pt]{\text}([xshift=-8pt]l\e|-bbs);
\end{tikzpicture}
    }}
    % A blank line here like a new paragraph so next picture is placed below
    \subfloat[][Sub figure second]{\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{
         \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=12pt,
        ylabel={$\mathcal{J}$ of WM},
        nodes near coords,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90},
        xtick = data,
        table/header=false,
        table/row sep=\\,
        xticklabels from table={\footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize 
          % wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          % \footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\
          }{[index]0},
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper}
      %  legend pos=north west
    ]
     \legend{1\%, 5\%}
   \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{1\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\};
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{3\\2\\8\\4\\4\\2\\};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,3,4,7,8,11}{\coordinate(l#1)at(axis cs:#1,0);}
    \end{axis}
    \coordinate(bbs)at(current bounding box.south);
    \foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\s=int(4*\i-1)},evaluate={\e=int(4*(\i-1))}] \text in {Axial,Coronial}
      \draw[decorate,decoration=brace]([xshift=8pt]l\s|-bbs)--node[below=5pt]{\text}([xshift=-8pt]l\e|-bbs);
\end{tikzpicture}
    }}
    \caption{Accuracies Comparision}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

To reiterate, Please, note that I want the percentage on top of every bar; the bar chart should be aligned properly with axial, coronial. Also, it would be great if someone could help me use patterns for each bar.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to include the percentage on top of every bar plot" - Is this already solved, as there are the number on top of every bar?

Comment: I mean, I want to add the percentage beside every number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- Reduced example to be minimal

  - removed unneeded packages
  - removed second plot
- use `xticklabel style={font=\footnotesize}` to set the size only once
- use the correct numbers here: `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,2,3,5}{...}`

  - these numbers correpond to the x position in the plot
- change the calculations in the `foreach` loop, to have the correct size of 3:

  `evaluate={\s=int(3*\i-1)}, evaluate={\e=int(3*(\i-1))}`
- a percentage sign can be added with the option:

  `nodes near coords*={\footnotesize \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}`

  - but I wouldn't recommend this, as it need more space and is unnecessary information

#### Code

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            ymin=0,
            width  = 12cm,
            height = 5cm,
            bar width=12pt,
            ylabel={$\mathcal{J}$ of WM},
            nodes near coords*={\footnotesize \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
            xticklabel style={rotate=90, font=\footnotesize},
            xtick = data,
            table/header=false,
            table/row sep=\\,
            xticklabels from table={%
                wells\\
                lemput\\
                wang\\
                wells\\
                lemput\\
                wang\\
            }{[index]0},
            enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper}
            %  legend pos=north west
        ]
        
            \legend{1\%, 5\%}
            \addplot[pattern=horizontal lines light blue] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{1\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\};
            \addplot[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=red] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{3\\2\\8\\4\\4\\2\\};
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,2,3,5}{
                \coordinate(l#1) at (axis cs:#1,0);
            }
        \end{axis}
        \coordinate (bbs) at (current bounding box.south);
        \foreach[count=\i, evaluate={\s=int(3*\i-1)}, evaluate={\e=int(3*(\i-1))}] \text in {Axial,Coronial}
            \draw[decorate,decoration=brace] ([xshift=8pt] l\s|-bbs) -- node[below=5pt] {\text} ([xshift=-8pt] l\e|-bbs);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Can you also show me how to align them side by side?
Like how I showed it in the question?

Comment: Just copy it and put it in the code structure you showed in your question? Else, you should ask a new question for that, as we usually want one question per post.